# Build select date and year inputs with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

In my Ruby on Rails application I have some form that needs inputs to select month and year. I do this with built in Rails select_date input:

```
 = select_date @date, :order => [ :month, :year], :discard_day => true
```

But now I want to know is there any way to the same easy with simple_form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously an old question but the answer is YES, you absolutely can do the same with simple_form.  Posted for others looking for this answer.

You'll pass `date` as the input type and then rather like the select_date form_for input helper, you'll pass `discard_day`

So it might look like this:

```
= f.input :your_date_field, as: :date,  discard_day: true
```

Answer (score 5):

Hello read a this documentation

**1.4 Other Helpers of Interest**
Other form controls worth mentioning are textareas, password fields, hidden fields, search fields, telephone fields, date fields, time fields, color fields, datetime fields, datetime-local fields, month fields, week fields, URL fields, email fields, number fields and range fields:

```
<%= text_area_tag(:message, "Hi, nice site", size: "24x6") %>
<%= password_field_tag(:password) %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:parent_id, "5") %>
<%= search_field(:user, :name) %>
<%= telephone_field(:user, :phone) %>
<%= date_field(:user, :born_on) %>
<%= datetime_field(:user, :meeting_time) %>
<%= datetime_local_field(:user, :graduation_day) %>
<%= month_field(:user, :birthday_month) %>
<%= week_field(:user, :birthday_week) %>
<%= url_field(:user, :homepage) %>
<%= email_field(:user, :address) %>
<%= color_field(:user, :favorite_color) %>
<%= time_field(:task, :started_at) %>
<%= number_field(:product, :price, in: 1.0..20.0, step: 0.5) %>
<%= range_field(:product, :discount, in: 1..100) %>
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

and more example examples here:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select

Comment: But my solution works perfectly. I also use date_select but now I want to find solution to have exactly the same with simple_form.

Comment: but documentation oficialy https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form  using a custom input o use a date inputs, regards

Comment: other solution is using a html select and jquery,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681875/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-date-using-bootstrap-datepicker <-- read this