# I cant get date value from bootstrap calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code to render a calendar with bootstrap.

However when I select a date, I cant get the value, not with .val() not with .text()

btw its a sharepoint page.

```
<h3>Fecha de cumpleaños</h3>
<div>
   <div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <div class='input-group date' id='dtFechaCumpleanios'>
               <input type='text' class="form-control" />
               <span class="input-group-addon">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                   </span>
               </span>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(function () {
           jQuery('#dtFechaCumpleanios').datetimepicker({
               format: 'DD/MM'
           });
       });
   </script>
```

[image]

Comment: how you are trying to get value?

Comment: What have you used to get the value? It should just be `$('input.form-control').val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this Link Good Explanation of to get date value from bootstrap date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681875/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-date-using-bootstrap-datepicker/)

Comment: Welcome to SO Hafix, link only answers are not future-proof. Try to extract the relevant info please :)