# Check if a date has been selected. Bootstrap input type date

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have some code where I have a simple *Bootstrap datepicker* `<input type="date"/>` I need to check whether a value has been selected using *JavaScript*. When I echo the current value of the *input* where the *date* hasn't been selected, I just get a *blank* and the condition under if statement always results to true. Can someone assist in how to check this correctly?

\EDIT/UPDATE
I can successfully get the value of the datepicker when a date has been selected. I use `var date=$('#date').val()` which works well when a date has been selected. But when a date hasn't been selected, it just returns a blank. I need to check for a situation where a date hasn't been selected and do something ... I have tried `if(date="")` and `if(date=null)` none of these are efficient. The function never jumps to the else. The if statement always results to true. Is there something I am doing wrong or is my approach totally out of question?

Comment: Check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681875/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-date-using-bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: @RaviHirani I can successfully get the value of the datepicker when a date has been selected. I use `var date=$('#date').val()` which works well when a date has been selected. But when a date hasn't been selected, it just returns a blank. I need to check for a situation where a date hasn't been selected and do something ... I have tried `if(date="")` and `if(date=null)` none of this are efficient. Based on that can you assist me?

Comment: You should use == instead of = . single = is an assignment operator while == checks the condition. You can also write if(date) to check date is selected or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, you should write

```
var selectedDate = $("#date").val();
if(selectedDate == "") {  // use == instead of = here. It will check condition
  alert("date is not selected");
}else{
  alert(selectedDate);
}
```

**Note**:- single `=` is an assignment operator. It assigns the value to variable. While `==` checks the condition. You can also write if(selectedDate) to check date is selected or not.