# How to increment date by one month in JavaScript? Receiving Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a `Bootstrap datepicker` in which the date is selected. Upon clicking the button `New Date`, the `date` that was selected in the `datepicker` should get incremented by one month.

I have the following code:

```
function getNewDate(){
    var date = new Date();
    date = $("#selectedDate").val();
    // alert(date);
    var newDate = new Date();
    newDate = date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1);
    // alert(newDate);
}
```

However, upon doing this, I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: date.getMonth is not a function

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You create a Date instance, but then you immediately overwrite it with the value of an element.

Comment: `.val()` returns a string.

Comment: @DavidG no, that works just fine; the Date API handles that correctly and you get a date in January of the next year.

Comment: `date = $("#selectedDate").val();` <- at this point you have a string stored in `date`, rather than a `Date` object as you probably expect.

Comment: @Pointy Oh, that's er, awful.

Comment: @DavidG it's *extremely* useful in practice.

Comment: @DavidG: Or pretty darn convenient. `d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 10)` will work just fine, whatever date `d` is.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yeah maybe, but it's non-obvious whereas something like `addMonths()` would be

Comment: @DavidG: JS dates don't have methods like `addMonths`.

Comment: @Cerbrus I know, I'm saying that would have been a better API.

Comment: Having `addX` still doesn't mean the overflow handling in `setX` is redundant, though.

Comment: newDate = date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1); results in a number which won't got into your date type.  Try  newDate = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1))

Comment: @Cerbrus No, but only having it inside there makes it impossible to know how to do it without resorting to docs/SO.

Comment: @Farasi78: `date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1)` mutates `date`, so that variable could just be used instead.

Comment: @Farasi78 I tried. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: are you sure $('selectedDate').val() is returning a valid date, even if in a string format?  Try console logging that

Comment: @Farasi78 Yes. I tested that with the alert();

Comment: @Farasi78 Upon running the code, I get the first alert that has the selectedDate. After that, I don't get the second alert with the newDate. On checking, I see that I have the error in the browser console.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Farasi78 Same. `Uncaught TypeError: date.getMonth is not a function
    at NewBudget (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:338), <anonymous>:88:51)`

Comment: Again, `date = $("#selectedDate").val();` does _not_ return `Date` object. It returns a string that you need to convert to a date.

Comment: @Cerbrus is right do this:  date = new Date($("#selectedDate").val()) and try again.

Comment: It worked! I tried `var date = new Date(dateString);`. Thank you @Cerbrus and @Farasi78

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery `.val()` returns a string, which then has to be parsed. The code below assumes that it actually is in a format that can be parsed. Best to use `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Furthermore it is important to know that `date.setMonth(...)` changes the underlying `date` object.

Also note that 'impossible dates' are rolled over into the next month, e.g. doing `date.setMonth(11)` on a source date of `2018-10-31` will result in the 'impossible date' `2018-11-31`, which then becomes `2018-12-01`.

Demo:

```js
function getNewDate() {
  var str = $("#selectedDate").val(); // get string
  console.log(str);

  var date = new Date(str); // parse string
  console.log(date);

  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1); // change date
  console.log(date);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="selectedDate" value="2018-12-20" />
<button onclick="getNewDate()">Add month</button>
```

Comment: Since OP mentions it's a Bootstrap datepicker, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681875/how-to-get-the-selected-date-value-while-using-bootstrap-datepicker) might be relevant.